# Rust ring crate cannot cross-compile to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu from Apple M1

Tags: c, linux, gcc, rust, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a Rust lambda from an Apple M1 with no luck. I follow some tutorials on the internet ([this](https://betterprogramming.pub/cross-compiling-rust-from-mac-to-linux-7fad5a454ab1), https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/1332)

#### What I did

- Add target 86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (`rustup target add 86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`).
- `arch -arm64 brew install SergioBenitez/osxct/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.
- Add `.cargo/config.toml` in the project directory.
- Install llvm `arch -arm64 brew install llvm`.

`config.toml` content:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/7.2.0/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc"
```

Result:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.20`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/myhome/lambda-function/target/debug/build/ring-b3b2f6ac56d4de6c/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CC
  TARGET_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  RUSTC_LINKER = Some("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/7.2.0/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CROSS_COMPILE
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CFLAGS
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")

  --- stderr
  running "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-4" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/Users/myhome/lambda-function/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/build/ring-4ea4043fbf2278a0/out/aesni-x86_64-elf.o" "/Users/myhome/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/pregenerated/aesni-x86_64-elf.S"
  thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute ["x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-4" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/Users/myhome/lambda-function/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/build/ring-4ea4043fbf2278a0/out/aesni-x86_64-elf.o" "/Users/myhome/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/pregenerated/aesni-x86_64-elf.S"]: No such file or directory (os error 2)', /Users/myhome/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/build.rs:653:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Try running the build as `env CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/7.2.0/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu …`. In general, cross-compiling can be annoyingly difficult, you might want to use something like `cross-rs`.

Comment: I'll try `cross-rs`.

Comment: It seems `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` needs to be in your `PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cross-rs. The only drawback is that the build time now increases by a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Zig as a linker:

```bash
brew install zig
cargo install cargo-zigbuild
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
cargo zigbuild --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```